# Rotate String without g2d .rotate

Tags: java

I've got a program which enters a lot of strings next to lines (streets + streetnames)
Now I want to attach/align the streetnames on top of the streets.

But when im using the g2d.rotate, all of the streets rotate as well.

So is there another simple way to rotate a String?

Comment: Some sample code would be appreciated.

Comment: @Wouter Krooshof this question about Maps and labels with formatting of StreetNames was asked here a few times,

Answer (score 3):

Once you've drawn the string in the preferred orientation, you will need to return to the original rotation.

```
// rotated 90 degrees around world origin
g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(90));
g2d.drawString("Broadway", 0, 50);

// rotated -90 degrees around world origin
g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(-90));
g2d.setColor(Color.GRAY.darker());
g2d.fillRect(50, 50, 50, 50);
```

You can also use transforms using the class `AffineTransform`. You can find more details on [Transforming Shapes, Text, and Images (The Java ™ Tutorials> 2D Graphics> Advanced Topics in Java2D)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html)